# Upload file to PHP using Python

Tags: python

This is still not working, I think it may be my OS.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by it is not working, and how does that mark the question as unaswered. You changed all the content of your question to a commend on your OS?

Comment: Sorry that was rash of me, it worked then it didn't after a windows update, I think i may have deleted something so my python code stopped working.

Comment: Anyway your PHP script was working, so it was idiotic of me to remove the answered tag, the problem was on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python part is fine. What you need to change is your `php` script to something like that:

```
<?php
$filename = "test.pdf";
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
echo("Done uploading");
?>
```

You of course have to make sure that a file with the same filename does not already exist. For info about php file uploading check http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.

Comment: Please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php. The second argument of the `move_uploaded_file` function takes the destination you wish the file to be moved at. This would be the path, absolute or relative, including the filename.